# Android Shared Prefs Map key-values to ArrayList to ListView row - UPDATED

Tags: java, android, arraylist, simpleadapter

Here's what I'm trying to do:
- Retrieve a Map of key-value pairs from a SharedPreferences object (User#, Name)
- write those key-value pairs into an ArrayList such that I can
- use them to populate a ListView with each row containing BOTH the key and the value like so:

1. User 1 - Joe R.
2. User 2 - Frank B.

etc

---

UPDATE: 
so after taking a good long look at the SimpleAdapter class, and talking with some wiser more knowledgable folks - I'm a lot closer than I was... but still not all the way there.

here's what I have now:

```
public class LogHistory extends ListActivity {

static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private static final String KEY = null;
private static final String VALUE = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.log_history);

    SharedPreferences logPrefs = getSharedPreferences(LoginField.PREFSNAME, 0);
    Map<String, ?> logMap = logPrefs.getAll();

    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> e : logMap.entrySet()) {
        HashMap<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String mKey = e.getKey();
        String mValue = (String) e.getValue();
        row.put(KEY, mKey);
        row.put(VALUE, mValue);
        list.add(row);

        // FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES
        makeToast(mKey);
        makeToast(mValue);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        this,
            list,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY, VALUE },
            new int[] {R.id.item1, R.id.item2}
    );

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This sort of works - but only half way... what I get as a result is a list of the VALUES in *both* columns...

HOWEVER the makeToast function returns the *proper values* for both the KEY and the VALUE - so the problem *must* be in the SimpleAdapter method yes??

assistance would be great - homework is due tonight! :-0

Comment: I updated my answer. Provide a meaninful name into those final String keys. The INDEXES "KEY" and "VALUE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for "custom listview", "listview custom adapter" and those things. "two line listview item layout"...

See [this example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html). There are others on Google.

Basically, you can create a `ArrayList<Hashmap<String,String>>`, which is your data container. You add values to that creating as many `HashMap<String, String>` objects as you need and using `list.add(yourHashMap)`, where list is the ArrayList.

At the end you feed that to a `SimpleAdapter` (there are other methods, but this works without much trouble).

Check the docs to see how each thing works exactly.

---

You are nulling your index keys. Put a name into those final Strings.

> This sort of works - but only half way... what I get as a result is a list of the VALUES in both columns...
>   HOWEVER the makeToast function returns the proper values for both the KEY and the VALUE - so the problem must be in the SimpleAdapter method yes??

As I said, no. When you do this:

```
row.put(KEY, mKey);
row.put(VALUE, mValue);
```

You are not providing a meaninful difference between `KEY` and `VALUE`, because both are null. It's something like putting all things into the *same* column.

Your mistake into reasoning that is because the Toast test you created yourself test only the correctness of the values, not the columns:

```
makeToast(mKey);
makeToast(mValue);
```

In that you test only the values. ;) You ***assume*** that the columns are right, and that the mistake could only be in the values, which is exactly the opposite.

First rule of dealing with computers: computers never assume LOL. ;-)

Comment: thank you - SimpleAdapter was the missing piece of the puzzle - I had been banging my head against the wall looking for solutions for the ArrayAdapter.

Forest for the trees and all that.

Comment: You're welcome! The other way would be to provide your own, custom adapter. Something like this: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/ , which allows for a better control and abstraction. However, I'd start with what I posted above if your needs don't demand much. Good luck!

Comment: FWIW - I also found this link helpful: http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/

Comment: This one works almost exactly like what I posted first, but the concept is *exactly* the same. He feeds a lot of HashMap<String, String> into a List (I provided you an ArrayList, but whatever...) and at the end he feeds all that to a SimpleAdapter. As I said, just the same. ;-)

Comment: so - after spending the last hour or so trying to make this work I think someone somewhere at Google is having a good hard laugh at naming this "SIMPLEAdapter"...  ;-p

Comment: ok - i have it all working from a static data set - but I'm stuck on how to iterate through the SharedPrefs Map data and feed it into a HashMap... or is it a cast conversion?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. If I understand correctly, you can use a for loop like in the example posted, and after you finish each, you add to the list. If it's more complicated than that, I suggest you post another question. Because if I can't answer, others certainly will. This question is already solved, you won't get much attention. My suggestion.

Comment: the 'null' was the problem David! thanks for your assistance, I'm not totally sure WHY having the same initial value should do this - but I'm puzzling through it. Cheers for your help!

Comment: Think of this: "if it's 'null', place it as a 'value', else if it's 'null', place it as 'key'". Since both are null, there is no way you could fit things into "KEY", since they are the same and will fit first into the "VALUE" bucket. Hence the need for different indexes.

Comment: hmmm.... ok. but why do the variables have a 'null' value AFTER they've been assigned values from the Map? I 'assumed' ;-p that these lines would assign values to both variables: String mKey = e.getKey(); String mValue = (String) e.getValue(); and since it's happening before the put() I don't understand why they still have a 'null' value when the put()s happen! BTW I tested using the same initial values for both ('init') and problem was exactly the same, so obviously you're totally right!

Comment: and BTW - thanks again for all your help David. I really appreciate it. there are a lot of guys around here who just care about getting their points and once you check that checkmark you don't hear anything more. cheers.

Comment: I'm not like that. :-) About your thinking, you're wrong because the put command does *NOT* change the "KEY" and "VALUE" variables. The put command uses those variables as a reference to where to put mKey and mValue in each "for" loop. Think of the use of those variables in the put command as a road sign: if two road signs point to the same place, the driver won't know where to put mKey and mValue. The put command do *not* assign to them, it uses them as a direction to put the mKey and mValue values. I hope this example help clear your doubts.

Comment: If I were interested in badges and points, I wouldn't be answering you right now when I'm just 4 upvotes from gaining the famous Mortarboard badge today. Just for you to have an idea. :-)

Comment: ahhh... I finally get it! for some reason I was confusing the mKey and mValue assignments with the KEY and VALUE put()s!